# Project setup advice with Rstudio, make and git needed

Tags: git, r, makefile, project

I am moving from a manual to an automated process and need help.

I have a directory with csv data files that feed a bevy of R routines for analysis. The directory is named with the date of creation BUT not all files in the directory are updated

Directories (data2012-11-26, for example) always has seven elements:

```
BW_Weekly.csv
BW_Monthly.csv
BW_Yearly.csv
CLR_Weekly.csv
CLR_Monthly.csv
CLR_Yearly.csv
Special_Weekly.csv
```

the other constraints - I sometimes have to go back to a previous date directory to analyze an older set. the "weekly" files are updated weekly, the "monthly" and "yearly" files are updated once a month.

My workflow today is: receive the weekly files via email on every Monday and the monthly/yearly files on the first Monday of the next month (ie next Monday, I will receive the November updates in the monthly/yearly files. Create a new directory with the Monday date. Copy the current monthly/yearly files to that directory. Save the weekly files from email to that new directory. Update a variable name in the R analysis file with the new directory name. Run(source) the analysis, plot results. VERY MANUAL.

I was trying to figure out how to use git (and maybe a makefile rule or two) to do this in a more automated process. -ANY ADVICE YOU HAVE IS APPRECIATED-

My somewhat muddled idea is to use git to commit/tag the files as they arrive. Then using a makefile rule to 1)check out latest data files 2) run / plot the results into pdf 3) view the pdfs for analysis. PLUS I can stop editing a file over and over and over ...

This would allow something along the lines:

```
git checkout data2012-11-26 (or whatever Monday date I want)
build all (in RStudio Build Tab ideally)
```

The files are large - roughly 15-20MB per csv file. Can git handle that?
And could someone help with the make rules that could get this done (I am no good at anything other than the bare minimum of makefile rules) ... maybe even doing the checkout too?

Open to using new file naming conventions - if you think that would help.

Comment: Does your analysis leverage the historical CSV data? Or just the current week's 7 files?

Comment: If you want to end up with pdfs, then maybe a good first step would be to turn your current analysis routine into an Rmarkdown file, complete with all the graphs you need?

Comment: No, the analysis is only based on the current set of files. However, I have a need to go back in time to rerun the analysis. Not often, but enough that I want to plan for it.

Comment: As for the Rmarkdown - yes, that is included in the "R analysis". I essentially have one master script that does everything and produces the PDFs automatically. Not to go into it here, but the script is very automatic - produces HTML and PDF results (via knitr, Rmarkdown, and Pandoc). Most of my work is in the front end of getting all the data files in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would indeed recommend make for this.  I do something very similar, and have wrestled with the best way to make the analysis repeatable, modular and automated.  I recently posted [this](https://github.com/paulhurleyuk/AnalysisWorkflowSkeleton) to github  (hence me finding this post when searching).  No hard and fast answers here, but here's some thoughts.

- Make your analysis modular. I have separate R files to get the data, then clean, then process, then produce report elements, then produce the report.
- Make all the scripts access one standard set of data, then you can push those to git and leave git to the version control and don't have to update the scripts for different data sets
- Create a makefile for your analysis that specifies output for each step and how it's performed, then make will check all your dependencies

Then you can overwrite any new data files and just run make to update everything.  Running an old analysis would be simple as checking out that branch and running the analysis again.